# getting value of custom attributes using XPATH and PHP

Tags: php, curl, xpath

I am trying to extract the data stored in a list. The troubling piece is the "custom-data" entity.

```
 <li id="myid" custom-data="123456789" class="search-query">
    ...lots of child elements
```

I get all the string data with querying DomXPath object for "search-query" and than extract it with this the code below.

```
$id = $exampleXPath->query("//li[@class='search-query']");

foreach ($id as $element) {
    $nodes = $element->childNodes;
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        echo "$node->nodeValue<br>";

    }
}
```

I would like to also get the value of "custom-data" of each "search-query" object, but I don't how to get it. Any ideas?

Comment: is class="search-query" is unique on yout HTML DOM?

Comment: nope, all <li> elements have it. But I want to target all <li> so that is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have reference to all "search-query" elements, so getting the attribute should be as straightforward as calling [`getAttribute("attribute_name")`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) on each element:

```
$custom_data = $element->getAttribute("custom-data");
```